# Android Studio:The app won't run unless you update Google Play services

Tags: android, google-maps

[The app won't run unless you update Google Play services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACqM5.png)

any solution ?

Comment: so just : update Google Play services

Answer (score 0):

Some apps like pushnotification and google maps wont run without google play services. so kindly `Install / Update` `Google Play Services`

From Android SDK Manager, install: Extras: Google Play services